# Apache server-status not showing "Server Load"

Tags: apache-2.2

> **Apache's server-status page** displays information from mod_status.
>
> **It is not displaying Server load:**

[image]

> But as you'll notice, the [Apache.org/server-status](https://www.apache.org/server-status) status page *does show* **Server load**:

[image]

> On previous servers I have used it always displays.
>
> **Why is this? How can *Server load* be enabled**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Load is only displayed on the `/server-status` page for Apache v2.4. You will need to upgrade to see it